# SQL CASE LIKE with multiple choices

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-like

In my query I have following part of the code:

```
CASE WHEN Field1 LIKE '%choice1%' OR Field1 LIKE '%Choice1%' .... THEN 'category 1'
     WHEN Field1 LIKE '%choicea%' OR Field1 LIKE '%Choiceb%' .... THEN 'category 2'
END AS 'Cats'
```

I have numerous of those choices (1line about 20), (2line about 15 and son on).

Can I do something to make my code cleaner, something that I usually use `IN` for?

Example:

```
CASE WHEN Field1 IN LIKE ('%choice1'.'%choice2%',...) THEN 'category 1'
     WHEN Field1 IN LIKE ('%choicea'.'%choiceb%',...) THEN 'category 2'
END AS 'Cats'
```

P.S. I heard that I can use somehow those `||` but I can't find in google how to use them.

What do you think about this problem?

Comment: What RDMS and version are you using?

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to clean it would be if you can find a pattern that matches more than one of the conditions, using the wildcards shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp. There is no way to specify multiple patterns in a single LIKE condition.

Comment: If your DBMS supports Regular Expressions you could express all Ors of a WHEN with a REGEXP_SIMILAR. How often gets `Field1` updated? I would add a new column, update to the matching category and then assign it during each insert/update

Comment: @Pixalated I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @Chris Flynn I tried Wildcard and it doesn't help

Comment: @dnoeth It will be updated every time I will be running it so probably once a week. But I will be adding new choices and no deleting the old ones.

Comment: When you update once a week and run lots of SELECTs in-between it's well worth maintaining an extra column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those choices are already known, put them in a table and use a join:

```
SELECT Field1, c.Category
FROM MainTable 
LEFT JOIN Choices c ON Field1 LIKE ('%' + c.Choice + '%')
```

**Update:**
If there are sub-strings inside one category, add a `DISTINCT` to this query.

Comment: This will return the same row multiple times if `Field1` matches multiple `LIKE`.

Comment: @dnoeth I also thought of that. If the choices are unique, and not sub string of each other, that would not happen. Otherwise it has to be managed to just select the first match just like the `CASE`, but this does not sound to be the case.

Comment: Ok, this changes a lot. Actually some of them are sub strings of others.

Comment: In those cases which category would you like to be selected then?

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood you. 

they will be substrings but under one category. 

e.g.
CASE WHEN Field1 LIKE '%wifi%' OR Field1 LIKE '%wif%' THEN 'cat1'
          WHEN Field1 LIKE '%mms3%' OR Field1 LIKE '%mms%' THEN 'cat2'
END

Comment: Then you can just keep the shortest ones as they are more general and remove the others, as if one string matches the longer ones it would also match the shortest. In your example anything that matches `LIKE '%wifi%'` or `LIKE '%wifo%'` would also match `LIKE '%wif%'`, so just keep the `LIKE '%wif%'`.

Comment: Even if the substrings where under different categories you'd better make the decision early and keep just one to clean and clear up things, unless you want to cascade mapping choices to categories from longer matches to shorter matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think your using SQL for something it isn't designed for. Having that many like statements is going to cause your query to absolutely devastate the resources on the SQL server, and when you get more rows than a demo db you are going to have a runtime that makes your users cry.

If you need this kind of information you need to try one of these things:

1.Make new columns to store the data you are trying to extract, and write update statements to parse out that says. For example, if you have case text like 'warning%' make an isWarning bit column, or a type varchar and store 'Warning' in it

2. Select the data back from the db without the case/like and perform that lookup in your business code afterwards

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was aware of how this will slow down my query, but I have only about 20k rows therefore I didn't treat it as real danger.

Answer (score 0):

If your logic still works with exact matches, you can try the decode() function, I know Oracle DB supports it: http://psoug.org/reference/decode_case.html .

Comment: I am not familiar with decoding, thanks for source. I will read more.

Comment: `DECODE` is deprecated Oracle syntax, similar to a simple `CASE x WHEN`, there's no way to use it for this purpose.